# Load innerHTML data in input field on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I'm trying to auto fill the data in `input field` which is shown in `<div id="demo"></div>`. How do I go about doing it?

I tried this but it's not working:

```
<input id="demo" type="text" />
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/z6m3824c/

HTML

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

JS:

```
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
 {
if (navigator.geolocation)
{
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
}
else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
}
function showPosition(position)
{
x.innerHTML="" + position.coords.latitude + 
", " + position.coords.longitude;  
}
getLocation()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input field has value. 
Try this:

```
<input id="demo" type="text" onLoad="" />
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
 {
   if (navigator.geolocation)
 {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
 }
  else{x.value="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
 }
 function showPosition(position)
 {
   x.value="" + position.coords.latitude + 
   ", " + position.coords.longitude; 
 }
 getLocation()
```

Comment: This isn't working. It only works if i put the `id` in DIV but not in INPUT.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much :)